# Please help me identity this part

Tags: part-identification

I was inadvertently shipped a car part instead of the golf clubs I ordered.  Shipper told me to keep the part, but I have no idea what it is.  There are no markings or part numbers on the item.  I hate to recycle the part.  Thank you for your help[image]

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! It's a driveshaft, but to what, I wouldn't know. Was there any kind of part number which came on the box or documentation with the part? There might even be something stamped (in ink or in the metal) on the part itself. Yah, that surely doesn't look like a set of golf clubs! :o)

Comment: Like to see you get out of the sand with that... But looks like it could be a pto drive possibly.

Comment: Thank you for the replies so far.  Unfortunately, there is nothing stamped on the part. Not a number, letter or symbol.  I guess it’s generic.  I hate to recycle it, but that seems like my only option.